# PYTHON: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for TESTCASE

Tags: python, error-handling, testcase

im not understanding why I'm getting this errors because when I pass 'height' as -1, it must change 'error' to 'Height must be .GE to zero'
and that tests case passed.

However when I test base case 0. It says there is nothing in the list? can someone explain why? or tell me what's wrong with my code

```
def adjust(values):
      #default
      height = 0

      if ('height' in values):
          try:
          height = float(values['height'])
      except ValueError:
          values['error'] = 'non-numeric height'
          return values

      if height < 0:
          values['error'] = 'Heights needs to be .GE 0'
          return values
```

TEST CASE: 100_101 failed and 100_120 passed

```
def test100_010HeightLowBound(self):
    dict = nav.adjust({'op': 'adjust', 'observation': '3d.13','height': '0'})
    self.assertEquals('0', dict['height'])

def test100_020OutofBound(self):
    dict = nav.adjust({'op': 'adjust', 'observation': '3d1.3', 'height': '-1'})
    self.assertEquals('Heights needs to be .GE 0', dict['error'])
```

Error Generation because of failed test:
self.assertEquals('0', dict['height'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: but if im just testing to check if height is in there dictionary correctly, can I not call dict['height'] to check? adjust is an incomplete function that will eventually return values that has a dictionary of height, temperature and other statistics

Comment: not a good idea to use a datatype as the name of your variable

Answer (score 0):

If the `height` key exists, and `height >= 0`, nothing will be returned. That means `dict` will be `None`, and you'll get the error you're getting. You just need to ensure that a usable value is returned in all instances.

```
def adjust(values):
      height = 0

      if ('height' in values):
          try:
             height = float(values['height'])

          except ValueError:
              values['error'] = 'non-numeric height'
              return values

      if height < 0:
          values['error'] = 'Heights needs to be .GE 0'

      return values # Return values regardless of the previous checks
```

It doesn't even seem necessary to return `values` though. All you're doing is mutating the parameter. You could just use the mutated parameter.

```
def adjust2(values):
      height = 0

      if ('height' in values):
          try:
              height = float(values['height'])

          except ValueError:
              values['error'] = 'non-numeric height'
              return

      if height < 0:
          values['error'] = 'Heights needs to be .GE 0'

def test100_010HeightLowBound(self):
    data = {'op': 'adjust', 'observation': '3d.13','height': '0'}
    nav.adjust(data)
    self.assertEquals('0', data['height'])
```

---

And as noted in the comments, naming a variable the same name as a built-in is a bad idea. I renamed `dict` to `data` so you aren't shadowing the built-in `dict` function.